# Bootstrap 4 Carousel Multiple Images Slide Delay

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

I am trying to use this script https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/dl6ez to implement the slider on a website. One problem with this slider is, when I assign a background to the website, e.g. red like on this example https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/6X3j7 it starts to slide the images with delay. Any idea what makes the issue? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please specify how are you using the styles, and paste your code so that we can give you a more detailed answer. The animation is done by owl-carousel script so i dont think it has anything to do with your styles. 
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html
check this website for more detail documentation.

Comment: I have provided examples of the issue with defined background in the links. Isn't my question clear?